# Displaying Outlook calendars items on a large LCD

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, external-display, calendar

We have a large LCD in our IT department which we'd like to use to show where my colleagues are based on the current entry in their shared Outlook calendar.
We could use the calendar screen but it's just too small with 5-6 users on it.

Is there a way to scrape the information and display it in, say, a live Powerpoint view which updates every 5 mins?

Need to have nice large text which you can see from the other side of the room.
I've tried googling this but have had no luck so far.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple options for creating your own connection to the calendar:

- [Office Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.aspx) on a machine with Outlook installed.
- Pull info from Exhcange server (2010+) with [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa579187(v=exchg.140).aspx).

For example, we use #2 (EWS) here in a couple in-house C# web applications.  One for importing Gmail contacts into Exchange, and another for pulling specific calendar entries from an Exchange Public Calendar, which then offers the entries as a JSONP web service that we pull into HTML via jQuery's AJAX commands.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question, I'll give that a try. Regards